# Have multiple AOS, user can only print from one of them

Tags: windows, printing, dynamics-ax-2012

We have three dynamics ax 2012 instances on three separate servers and normally users don't have any problems printing from either one of them.

But this new user can only seem to print from one of them. Other users that go through the same printer have no problems and I've been unable to locate any differences.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to do is examine differences between the AOS servers and client configurations. That means logging into each AOS. Then examine/confirm that the client configuration (.axc) the user vs other users are all the same.

Specifically look at the highlighted checkboxes relating to printer mapping in the image below. I'm not saying one configuration is right or wrong, it all depends on your environment, but just look for differences.

The screenshots below are from my development environment, so don't think these are what they *should* be.

[image]

The second thing to do is log directly onto the AOSs, look and see what system account is running the AOS service, then RDP to the AOS **as that user account**. Then look at the installed printers and confirm they are similar across the AOSs.

Printing can be a pain in AX, but I suspect your new user does not have the printer installed locally and it is installed on only 1 AOS, so when they connect to that AOS, it may be getting mapped. If they connect to the other AOSs, perhaps AX is enumerating all of the printers it finds across all 3 AOSs, but your user happens to not have it installed where others may?

I'd guess you'll need to install the printer(s) on the other 2 AOSs **while logged in as the AOS user**.